# OpenSSL 111 API Decryp password

Tags: c, api, encryption, openssl

I encrypt password by OpenSSL enc utility:

`echo "Hello" | openssl enc -e -a -aes-256-cbc -k 12345`

And I want to decrypt this password into my program by the next way:

```
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init( ctx );

    /************************ Decryption Next *************************************************/

    plaintext_ptr = txtbuf ;        /* Use txtbuf for plain text output */
    plaintext_len = strlen(encrypted_pass)+256; 
        
    status = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(    ctx , 
                EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                NULL ,
                key , 
                iv );

    ciphertext_len = strlen((char*)ciphertext_ptr);

    status = EVP_DecryptUpdate( ctx , 
                plaintext_ptr , &outlen ,
                ciphertext_ptr , ciphertext_len ); 

    printf ("DecryptUpdate() writes %d bytes \n", outlen);

    plaintext_len = outlen;         /* Initial decryption       */

    plaintext_ptr += outlen;        /* adjust decrypted O/P buffer  */


    status = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(   ctx , 
                plaintext_ptr , 
                &outlen );

    printf ("DecryptFinal_ex() writes %d bytes \n", outlen );

    plaintext_len += outlen ;   /* Total decryption with padding    */
    plaintext_ptr += outlen;    /* adjust decrypted O/P buffer      */

    *plaintext_ptr='\0';    /* terminate string at data's end   */

    printf("Decrypted value is: \n%s \n", txtbuf );

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free( ctx );
```

`encrypted_pass = "U2FsdGVkX1/AY/5+DH9G76XPfQ5ygzK440THY0c9nbw="`
`key = "12345"`

And this program returns the wrong result, can you give me advice on what I do wrong?

Comment: It would be better if you post an example code with executable main, so we can compile it and we try to solve the problem.

Comment: With _-k_ a password is specified and not a key. With a password, a password-based key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`) is implicitly used to derive a key and IV. This is missing in the C code (i.e. `key = "12345"` is wrong). By the way, from where do you get the IV in the C code? With _-K_ and _-iv_ key and IV can be specified directly (hex encoded).